# How to create a python backtrace in form of a string?

Tags: python-3.x

To print a backtrace in python on can use the following code:

```
import traceback
....
traceback.print_stack()
```

However, I need the `backtrace` to be used as a string for a logger, something like this:

```
logger.debug(traceback.print_stack())
```

which, in this case, does not work. How to *most simply* get the backtrace to the logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback module is full of "format" functions which docuemtnation you can see here https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

One of which is the `format_stack` - just pass it a Python frame object, o(by default it uses the current frame) - and it returns you a list of strings, each with the file path and line content of the running position:

```
logger.debug("\n".join(traceback.format_stack()) )
```

Or, if you have an exception traceback object, which you can retrieve with a call to `sys.last_traceback` , you simply pass it's `tb_frame` attribute to the format_stack function:

```
logger.debug("\n".join(traceback.format_stack(sys.last_traceback().tb_frame)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The *simple* way of logging the traceback if an exception exists:

```
logger.debug(traceback.format_exc())
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html